# Java Transformer - skip attributes with defaults in DTD

Tags: xslt, dtd

I am trying to use a Java Transformer to properly add whitespace to my XML stream.  It does correctly format it, but my DTD has the following definition for my "page" element attributes:

```
<!ATTLIST page 
      title CDATA #REQUIRED
      subtitle CDATA #IMPLIED
      classifier CDATA #IMPLIED
      pagenum CDATA #IMPLIED
      border CDATA "false">
```

the problem is with the border attribute.  When the XMLStreamWriter is written out I have a value like:

```
<page title="Belgium">...</page>
```

But when I call the transformer on it it correctly formats the element but it adds the "border" attribute:

```
<page title="Belgium" border="false">
    ...
</page>
```

Is there a way to specify in the transformer to "skip" writing attributes with defaults if not specified?

Note: I know I should convert to an XSD (this DTD goes back a ways).  I could also possibly modify border to be #IMPLIED since I am not really using it anymore (ie. I can imply in the code that reads this XML that it is false unless specified)

Solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, XSLT 1.0 has no awareness of which values come from the instance document and which come from defaults in the DTD or schema. I'm not sure offhand whether XSLT 2.0 added that to its dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Saxon has an option for this: -expand:off

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/index.html#!using-xsl/commandline

The equivalent if you're using the Java API is FeatureKeys.EXPAND_ATTRIBUTE_DEFAULTS, which you can supply as an option to the TransformerFactory in JAXP.